# Show $x_n=\frac{\sin1}{2}+\frac{\sin(2)}{2^2}+...+\frac{\sin(n)}{2^n}$, converges

Tags: analysis

Show $x_n=\frac{\sin(1)}{2}+\frac{\sin(2)}{2^2}+...+\frac{\sin(n)}{2^n}$, converges. One can show it by showing $x_n$ is Cauchy.
I'm looking for cool ways to prove it?

Comment: $x_n$ is the imaginary part of a converging geometric series $$x_n = \Im  \left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{e^i}{2}\right)^n\right]
\to \Im \left[ \frac{1}{1 - \frac{e^i}{2}}\right] = \frac{2\sin(1)}{5-4\cos(1)}
$$

Comment: @achillehui Make that an answer.

Answer (score 5):

One simple way is using that $|\sin(n)|\leq 1$, so

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin(n)}{2^n}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{|\sin(n)|}{2^n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2^n},$$

which clearly converges.

Comment: for $N\to\infty$ this final sum $\to 1$ so we can say that $\sum\le 1$?

Comment: @HenryLee Yes, we can.